# WordPress: How do I customize "Lost your password" text on login page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I realize this is probably simple, but I can't figure out how to change the "Lost your password" text on the WordPress login page.

On the login page, there is a link that says, "Lost your password," and I want to change that text to read something like, "Get a new password." I'm just not sure what function to use to overwrite that text in the child theme.

[image: Screenshot of wordpress login screen]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Most decent text editors ( Notepad++, Ultraedit etc ) have a "Find in Files" or "Find in Folder" facility - do a search would be one way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986532/7186739

Answer (score 12):

Change wordpress text "Lost your password?"

```
function change_lost_your_password ($text) {

             if ($text == 'Lost your password?'){
                 $text = 'Forgot Password?';

             }
                    return $text;
             }
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_lost_your_password' );
```

Answer (score 7):

To change this text or any text for that matter you can use the following function, it's almost the same Super Model's answer but documented and code standards validated.

```
/**
 * Change some text.
 *
 * @param String $text WordPress Text Stream.
 * @return String
 */
function acme_change_some_text( $text ) {
    if ( 'Lost your password?' === $text ) {
        $text = 'Forgot Your Password?';
    }

    // Important to return the text stream.
    return $text;
}

// Hook this function up.
add_action( 'gettext','acme_change_some_text' );
```

Here's a handy gif to explain what's happening.

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 2):

The function has several parameters to change the default settings. For instance, you can specify: the ID names of the form and its elements (for CSS styling), whether to print the "Remember Me" checkbox, and the URL a user is redirected to after a successful login (default is to stay on the same Page):

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => admin_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username custom text' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password custom text' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me custom text' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In custom text' ), //you can change here
        'remember' => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
} else { // If logged in:
    wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
    echo " | ";
    wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
}
?>
```

The form itself is generated by code in the WordPress `wp-includes/general-template.php` file. Because your custom login Page is different than the built-in WordPress login page (wp-login.php)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 6.1.0 adds the [lost_password_html_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/lost_password_html_link/) filter hook which gives us a new option on this front:

```php
/**
 * Replace password reset link text
 *
 * @param String $html_link HTML link to the lost password form.
 */
function _acme_better_pw_reset_text( $html_link )   {

    $link_text_default = 'Lost your password?';

    // (More intuitive for users who haven't yet set a password yet.)
    $link_text_new = 'Get a new password';

    $html_link = str_replace($link_text_default, $link_text_new, $html_link);

    return $html_link;

}
add_filter( 'lost_password_html_link', '_acme_better_pw_reset_text' );
```

The main potential benefit vs `gettext` is **lower risk of performance impact** since it only runs on the login page, not wp-admin or public-facing URLs. [A common suite of WordPress plugins may run `gettext` thousands of times per page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/#comment-5073). (That said, `gettext` might still be fine if it's just an exact string match like another user suggested here.)

You could also go one step further and use translated strings [like WordPress core does](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aa10c88a86508860a3732205ae555a71f615378e/wp-login.php#L1492)...

```php
$link_text_default = __( 'Lost your password?', 'acme' );

$link_text_new = __( 'Get a new password', 'acme' );
```

...but if you're internationalizing in this way, you might want to change `str_replace` to `DOMDocument` or similar so you can target the display text specifically. Otherwise a malicious translator may be able to modify the reset link URL (since this hook acts upon the full `$link_html`).

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what was going on. I was looking in the default Wordpress login files for a solution, but this login form is actually coming from Woocommerce. So I was able to find the file containing the text and change it.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Avoid changing into the core files.